# Serve file download with variable contents. PHP

Tags: php

If we have the following

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="1">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['token']))
{    

    $v = 'NAME,COLOR
          jack,blue
          ivan,gold';

    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.csv\"");
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', gmmktime() - 3600) . ' GMT');
    //header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));

    echo $v;

}
```

When I run the script, the browser prompts me to download, when the file is downloaded and I check the contents, it also contains the HTML(above the $v data) markup in the file.

I wish to have a file consisting of just the **$v** variable data.

Comment: You should echo $v after the headers. It still puzzles me you get the source script as the csv content.

Comment: @amenadiel Will try that now, I was also shocked when I saw the php, seems kinda dangerous if this was in a production environment.
Edit - Its not the php I am seeing, but PHP error code and other html code. My bads

Comment: Sure it is. However, since you are sending the filename in the header, and the extension isn't php, it's sent as text. I hope echoing something avoids this flaw

Comment: @user3962268 There is no HTML in your code, so your output will not contain HTML unless you're seeing the HTML error output of PHP.  Post your actual code and what it's actually returning.

Comment: @amenadiel echoing it does now include it in the downloaded file, do you know how I can remove all the above information? It seem whatever is above the Header: section(procedurally) will be included in the file. So HTML, Other errors, other php echo statements etc.

Comment: @Brad I stripped out the form to allow easier reading, I realised now this is not good... - Edited my post to include.

Comment: I see. You should create an else block and print the form only if $_POST['token'] is not set. Make sure that <?php opening tag is the first element in the file and that nothing is printed before headers.

Comment: @amenadiel I have seperated it now into 2 seperate files, problem is resolved - Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could simply change the order of PHP and HTML in the code as shown – and then use `exit` after you output your download data to stop the rest of the “script” from being executed. (That would include stopping _any_ output after it, no matter whether it was created by PHP or static HTML.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you output will be output.  An HTTP request is for one resource at a time.  You can't expect to send a web page and not expect to have that as part of your file content.  PHP cannot read your mind and know what part of your code is for the browser, and what part is for the downloaded resource.

You need to make a separate script that does nothing but return a single resource... the file to be downloaded.  Start your script with `<?php`, no whitespace.  If your file is purely PHP (and it probably will be), don't end it with `?>` to avoid whitespace at the end.

Comment: This is where I have been going wrong all these years, I thought PHP COULD read my mind. Thanks!

Comment: @user3962268 It might make more sense if you take a look at the HTTP request/response data as it is sent over the wire.  Use a tool like Fiddler or a packet sniffer like Wireshark to see how it actually works behind the curtain.

Comment: It makes sense, I did not perceive everything in its procedural order and how its labelled - Until ofc you said it.